# how to open another app in a tabhost / how to open a word doc within a tabhost of android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, doc

i've been trying to create an app that could open multiple activities with the help of the tabhost. one of the support is i would like to open a word document within my app.

i know how to open one with other app, but i hope it could be open within my app rather then having the need to press back button to return to my app.

the code that i use to open word doc :

```
File file = new File
            (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/MLT/student.doc");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),  "application/msword");
startActivity(intent);
```

i tried to add it to my tab using

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/MLT/student.doc");
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),  "application/msword");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info").setIndicator("Info",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_info)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

but i get runtime error, with the main

```
01-12 13:16:32.945: E/AndroidRuntime(10066): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.infraware.polarisoffice (with uid 10053) to be run in process com.app.mlt (with uid 10128) "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this intent as content of your specified tab.

But you should be careful - there can be devices, that does not necessary apps for opening doc files, or there can be several apps for this. Any way it is better to use `Intent.createChooser()` method for such operations.

Comment: could you show the example ? as i'm not sure what you are saying

Comment: try do this: ... .setContent(Intent.createChooser(intent, "some string"));

Comment: i tried it. but instead of appearing within the tabhost, it opens the other app and exit mine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the MIME application/msword type it didn't work so I used application/vnd.ms-word